# Hands-free stenomask for speech recognition

Tags: microphones

I am looking for a hands-free [stenomask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenomask) for speech recognition. The [Sylencer SmartMic SM 100 and 200](http://talktech.com/products/speech-recognition-smartmic/) has a snap-on head-strap option available, but the strap is not comfortable. What are other good options?

I don't want the microphone to be fixed on a stand in front of me, like this one:

[image]

---

Here is the Sylencer SmartMic SM 100 and 200's snap-on head-strap option:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should this use a 3.5mm jack, or is there something else standard for these devices?

Comment: @Undo I believe jack is the standard. Otherwise I'm fine getting some adapters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hushme's stenomask:

- http://www.gethushme.com
- preorder only
- price: 189 USD

[image]

[image]

[image]