# Device to create a "personal acoustic zone" to prevent other from hearing what I say

Tags: audio

I am looking for a device to create a "personal zone" to prevent other from hearing what I say. E.g., if I seat in an open space office and give a phone call, I don't want other people to hear me.

I am aware of:

- [Muzo](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/muzo-personal-zone-creator-w-noise-blocking-tech-sound-sleep#/), which has a "Secret mode to protect speech privacy by Sound Masking", but the product isn't available yet (expected release date: spring 2017) and [some people](https://www.reddit.com/r/shittykickstarters/comments/4p67v0/muzo_your_personal_zone_creator_wtf_is_this_even/) weren't so optimistic about it on reddit.
- [stenomasks](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/479/40), but there are quite uncomfortable.

Since this Stack Exchange website focuses on electronic devices, if you have some ideas that doesn't involve electronic devices, you're welcome to share them on this question posted on Home Improvement: [Isolating a workstation located in an open space office](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/99326/6573).

Comment: I'm personally a big fan of a very loud stereo, with noise-cancelling headphones attached to your phone.

Comment: @AdamWykes Thanks, sorry I mean: I'm looking for a device that prevents other from hearing what I say, but I cannot ask people to wear headphones or earplugs.

Comment: What about a fan that faces away from you? Most phones are pretty good about filtering out background noise like a fan.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really say how effective it will be in an open space, but since your goal is to obfuscate the noise coming from your conversation, your options are pretty much limited to:

- containing your sound
- generating additional unrelated sound

Many psychiatrist's offices use [devices like these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HD0ELFK) outside the closed office door to act as a sonic barrier between noise in the room and noise in the hallway. It is a fairly low-tech solution as it is essentially a small, very noisy fan within an acoustic amplification chamber. It is adjustable somewhere between "medium" and "loud". Its effectiveness will depend on how loud you are being and how close you are to the door.

Source: my wife and I use this specific model to provide white noise when we sleep.